# How does Gazebo publish ROS messages?

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

HI does someone mind please explaining how exactly Gazebo is able to publish ROS topics on a high level?

My understanding is that Gazebo uses Google Protobuff and boost::ASIO to publish/subscribe topics between its own libraries (e.g. physics, rendering); however, how are these messages "converted" to ROS messages? My guess is that there is a Gazebo plugin to access one of the Gazebo libraries and in that plugin there is code to convert a Gazebo message to ROS message, initialise a ROS publisher, and then publish the ROS message, but can someone please confirm?

Thank you for your help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23118/how-does-gazebo-publish-ros-messages?/) by [brucec](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13434/brucec/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yup, you pretty much nailed it. There isn't an automatic "conversion", hence why you can't publish custom gazebo message types as ros messages without writing a bunch of code to do that conversion (or vice-versa). You can find some further explanations here:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=plugins_hello_world

and the source code for those plugins here:

https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1